How to estimate the supremum of absolute value of the $k$-th derivative of $e^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}}$ in $(-1,1)$?
I want to know, is there a function $f$ with simple form, such that $$\sup_{x\in(-1,1)}\left|\partial ^k_xe^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}}\right|<f(k) $$
I calculated the values:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Derivative Order} & \textbf{Upper Bound of Absolute Derivative} \\ \hline
1^{\text{st}} \text{ derivative} & 7.984298 \times 10^{-1} \\ \hline
2^{\text{nd}} \text{ derivative} & 7.749705 \times 10^{0} \\ \hline
3^{\text{rd}} \text{ derivative} & 1.863999 \times 10^{2} \\ \hline
4^{\text{th}} \text{ derivative} & 8.315890 \times 10^{3} \\ \hline
5^{\text{th}} \text{ derivative} & 5.963578 \times 10^{5} \\ \hline
6^{\text{th}} \text{ derivative} & 8.147475 \times 10^{7} \\ \hline
7^{\text{th}} \text{ derivative} & 1.454826 \times 10^{10} \\ \hline
8^{\text{th}} \text{ derivative} & 3.300901 \times 10^{12} \\ \hline
9^{\text{th}} \text{ derivative} & 9.291724 \times 10^{14} \\ \hline
10^{\text{th}} \text{ derivative} & 3.180404 \times 10^{17} \\ \hline
11^{\text{th}} \text{ derivative} & 1.405601 \times 10^{20} \\ \hline
12^{\text{th}} \text{ derivative} & 7.792935 \times 10^{22} \\ \hline
13^{\text{th}} \text{ derivative} & 4.959671 \times 10^{25} \\ \hline
14^{\text{th}} \text{ derivative} & 3.594702 \times 10^{28} \\ \hline
15^{\text{th}} \text{ derivative} & 2.945548 \times 10^{31} \\ \hline
16^{\text{th}} \text{ derivative} & 2.710682 \times 10^{34} \\ \hline
17^{\text{th}} \text{ derivative} & 3.081643 \times 10^{37} \\ \hline
18^{\text{th}} \text{ derivative} & 3.860508 \times 10^{40} \\ \hline
19^{\text{th}} \text{ derivative} & 5.307376 \times 10^{43} \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$
And it's obvious that $f(k)>>k^k$ because $19^{19}\approx 1.98\times10^{24}$. But we also have $f(k)<<2^{2^k}$ because $2^{2^{19}}\approx 2.596\times10^{157826}$. So is there anyway to determine the magnitude of $\sup_{x\in(-1,1)}\left|\partial ^k_xe^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}}\right|$? Or can we find a function which can dominate it?

Here is a logarithm line plot.

I think you're looking for a function of $k$? So then you should write $f(k) \gg k^k$ etc.

@p.s. yes, I've fixed the typo.

Could you add the plot of  the logarithm of the maximum value as a function of the order ?

@ClaudeLeibovici, Done.

@TaD. Thank you !

Maybe this: $$\frac{\partial ^k}{\partial x^k}\exp \left(\frac{1}{x^2-1}\right)=\\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } -\frac{(-1)^{2 m} x^{-k+2 m} \Gamma (1+2 m) , _1F_1(1+m;2;-1)}{\Gamma
(1-k+2 m)}=\\int_0^{\infty } -\frac{e^{-t} x^{-k} J_1\left(2 \sqrt{t}\right) , _2F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},1;\frac{1}{2}-\frac{k}{2},1-\frac{k}{2};t
x^2\right)}{\sqrt{t} \Gamma (1-k)} , dt$$ helps. Where: $ J_1$ is  the Bessel function of the first kind.
